# How to set up flask + celery with a app based structure?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flash, celery

I am trying to setup a flask app with celery using a divisional (or app) based structure, where each "app" may (or may not) have background tasks

```
  +---datascience
    |   |   app.py
    |   |   blueprints.py
    |   |   celery.py
    |   |   celeryconfig.py
    |   |   extensions.py
    |   |   settings.py
    |   |   __init__.py
    |   +---bar
    |   |   |   __init__.py
    |   |   |   tasks.py
    |   |   |   views.py
    |   |   +---templates
    |   +---foo
    |   |   |   __init__.py
    |   |   |   tasks.py
    |   |   |   views.py
    |   |   +---templates
    |   +---home
    |   |   |   __init__.py
    |   |   |   index.py
    |   |   +---templates
    |   +---static
    |   +---templates
```

Inside, `datascience/app.py` I have a make_celery function,

```
def make_celery(app=None, include=None):
    app = app or create_app()
    celery = Celery(
        app.import_name,
        backend=app.config['CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND'],
        broker=app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'],
        config_source='datascience.celeryconfig'
        # include=include
    )
    celery.conf.update(app.config)

    class ContextTask(celery.Task):
        def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            with app.app_context():
                return self.run(*args, **kwargs)

    celery.Task = ContextTask
    return celery
```

In `datascience/celery.py` I instantiate by make_celery function

```
from .app import make_celery

celery = make_celery()
```

However, I am having trouble running a celery worker.

I am running `celery worker -A datascience.celery:celery -l info` (from the directory above `datascience` I get a traceback like

```
  File "\myapp\datascience\hello\view.py", line 5, in <module> from .tasks import hello as _hello
  File "\myapp\datascience\hello\tasks.py", line 2, in <module>\ from datascience.celery import celery
ImportError: cannot import name 'celery'
```

My `datascience\hello\tasks.py` looks like

```
from datascience.celery import celery


@celery.task
def hello(name):
    return "Hello " + name
```

and `datascience\hello\view.py` looks like,

```
from datascience.blueprints import celery_test

from .tasks import hello as _hello

@celery_test.route('/')
def hello():
    name = request.args.get('name', 'john doe')
    result = _hello.delay(name)
    result.wait()
    return render_template('hello.html', result=result)
```

I can start my flask app and navigate to routes that I currently don't have any celery tasks, but I can't start a celery worker.

UPDATES:

In `datascience/celery.py` i updated it to as explained [here](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/next-steps.html).  I was able to get their example up an running if I moved tasks to `proj/foo/tasks` and set `include=['proj.foo.tasks']`, in which case I ran the example everything worked fine.  So I made the following updates in my project.

```
from .factory import make_celery

imports = ['datascience.hello.tasks']
celery = make_celery(include=imports)
```

In which I also updated my `make_celery` function to accept the `include` kwarg.
Now, I have `datascience/celery.py` and also `datascience/hello/tasks.py` for my hello world app.  Now If I run `celery -A datascience worker -l info` I get `AttributeError: module 'datascience' has no attribute 'celery'` and before that I get `AttributeError: module 'datascience' has no attribute 'app'`.

If I run `celery -A datascience.celery worker -l info` I get the same error as above.

```
  File "\myapp\datascience\hello\view.py", line 5, in <module> from .tasks import hello as _hello
  File "\myapp\datascience\hello\tasks.py", line 2, in <module>\ from datascience.celery import celery
ImportError: cannot import name 'celery'
```